# Add documentation to java annotation elements

Tags: java, annotations

I want to know how to add java doc to custom annotation and its elements. Like if one can see doc of **@NotBlank** by hovering over it (attaching screenshot)
[image]

Similar is the case for elements for that annotation if one hovers over it.

So how do I add this type of documentation to my annotation? I saw the class file for @NotBlank and didn't see any doc comment i.e. **/** */** used.

**Edit 1**: Below is the screenshot of the **message** element of **@NotNull** while hovering on the message element. So one can see the doc giving the default message while hovering but in the source code, there is no document on the **message** element using **/** */**. So in my custom annotation also I'm not getting the document of the **message** element while hovering. **How it is done?**

[image]

Comment: Did you look at the **source** file of the `@NotBlank` annotation, or the **decompiled class** file? Javadoc will not be present in the latter, only the former. And normal Javadoc comments is the way you add documentation to annotations, just like any other class, field, method, etc..

Comment: @user16320675 Slaw Thanks for that. Yes, I was looking into decompiled source code which does not have a doc. But still, one thing I didn't get is why on hovering on elements like **message** of annotation showing default value but there is none in source code https://github.com/jakartaee/validation/blob/2.0.1.Final/src/main/java/javax/validation/constraints/NotNull.java. (Don't know how to attach screenshot in comment.)

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The [message element](https://github.com/jakartaee/validation/blob/2.0.1.Final/src/main/java/javax/validation/constraints/NotNull.java#L39) for the `@NotNull` annotation you linked to **does** have a default value (the string after the `default` keyword).

Comment: @Slaw Check the **Edit 1** of the post.

Comment: The IDE likely just parses the source code and grabs the default value for that popup (i.e., it's not coming from Javadoc).

Comment: (I'm not sure exactly how default values are compiled for annotation elements, but I suppose another option is that the IDE, instead of parsing the source code, actually looks at the byte-code)